# Create and save account with localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, authentication, local-storage

I want to be able to create an account with username and password that is stored in localstorage, i do not want to use a database, i know this is not secure but it is not a serious website it will be used by me.

The following HTML shows a modal that opens up when i click the "Sign Up" button to create an account that will then be used to log in to the website.

(I would prefer if you can use JQuery in your answers)

HTML:

```
<div id="sign-up-modal">
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" id="close-sign-up">x</span>
    <p><label>Username</label><input type="text" id="sign-username"></p>
    <p><label>Password</label><input type="password" id="sign-password"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="sign-submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use simple javascript

```
 // to store 
localStorage.setItem("someLabel", "value");
// to retrive stored value
localStorage.getItem("someLabel");
```